# Python OOP - importing class from different file

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am trying to understand classes and I cannot access to class in different file. What I want to do: I have to files aaaa.py and unittest.py in folder temp. 
aaaa.py:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        print('Test')

    def function(self):
        print('Test3')
```

unittest.py:

```
import temp.aaaa

y = temp.aaaa.Test()
```

when I run unittest I get error:

```
AttributeError: module 'temp' has no attribute 'aaaa'
```

what is the problem?

edit: project structure:

```
->Project:
--> temp:
---> extr(folder)
---> __init__.py
---> aaaa.py
---> unittest.py
---> test.txt
```

Comment: Since you have two files in the same folder, you should `import aaaa`.

Comment: why are you importing temp.aaaa when your module name is aaaa.py ? just `import aaaa` or do you have different directory ?

Comment: he is using python3, implicit relative imports are not usable

Comment: show us your project structure

Comment: I added project structure in description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like:

First solution:

```
from aaaa import Test
x = Test()
```

Second solution:

```
from temp import aaaa
x= aaaa.Test()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The second solution works for me. It is so hard to understand these all classes things.

Answer (score 0):

To saying to Python that "temp" folder contains .py that you want to import you have to create a `__init__.py` file inside the "temp" folder.

[What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your filestructure is akin to the following:

```
root_package/
 |_ __init__.py
 |_ unittest.py
 |_ aaaa.py
```

In python3 you can no longer use implict relative imports, for example in `unittest.py`:

```
# not valid, implicit relative import
import aaaa 

# valid, explicit relative import
from . import aaaa 

# valid, absolute import
from root_package import aaaa
```

Whether you use absolute imports or explicit relative imports is a style question that still rages :)

Comment: I did like this:
from temp import aaaa
in aaaa I have class Test. And when I am using this 'y = aaaa.Test()' I am getting error: AttributeError: module 'temp.aaaa' has no attribute 'Test'

Comment: could you please add the output of `print(dir(aaaa))` above the line `y = aaaa.Test()` ?

Comment: ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'csv', 'json']
['StaticRecon', 'Test', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'collections', 'csv', 'json', 'unittest']

Comment: Why are there two lists? `dir(aaaa)` should return one list of all the attributes available in the `aaaa.py` module